# Wordpress filmstrip image gallery

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery

I spent hours looking for this kind of image gallery that will display as filmstrip, and when the 'click to enlarge' text is clicked as shown in the image below, a lightbox modal will display with the corresponding image.

I know UX wise this is not good, but the client wanted this, so I should stick with it :/

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good plugin that will provide the same functionality: https://wordpress.org/plugins/slideshow-gallery/